# How to detect which .NET runtime is being used (MS vs. Mono)?

Tags: c#, mono, clr

I would like to know during execution of a program whether it is being executed using the Mono runtime or the Microsoft runtime.

I'm currently using the following code to determine whether I'm on a MS CLR:

```
static bool IsMicrosoftCLR()
{
    return RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory().Contains("Microsoft");
}
```

However, this is somewhat dependent on the installation folder of the runtime and I'm not sure whether this will work on all installations.

Is there a better way to check for the current runtime?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

From the Mono Project's [Guide to Porting Winforms Applications](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_Winforms_Applications):

```
public static bool IsRunningOnMono ()
{
    return Type.GetType ("Mono.Runtime") != null;
}
```

I'm sure you'll have a lot more questions, so worth checking this guide and the [mono-forums](http://www.go-mono.com/forums/)

Comment: You might want to save (cache) the result as well, calling reflection  every time might be expensive.

Comment: Is it possible to detect dotnet-runtime too, or is that Mono also?

Answer (score 26):

You can check for the Mono Runtime Like this

```
bool IsRunningOnMono = (Type.GetType ("Mono.Runtime") != null);
```

Answer (score 14):

With the advent of C# 6, this can now be turned into a get-only property, so the actual check is only done once.

```
internal static bool HasMono { get; } = Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null;
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a version with caching that I'm using in my project:

```
public static class PlatformHelper
{
    private static readonly Lazy<bool> IsRunningOnMonoValue = new Lazy<bool>(() =>
    {
        return Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null;
    });

    public static bool IsRunningOnMono()
    {
        return IsRunningOnMonoValue.Value;
    }
}
```

As @ahmet alp balkan mentioned, caching is useful here if you're calling this frequently. By wrapping it in a `Lazy<bool>`, the reflection call only happens once.

Answer (score 7):

just run the below code..

```
static bool IsMicrosoftCLR()
{
    return (Type.GetType ("Mono.Runtime") == null)
}
```

Comment: "Mono not being the runtime" does not mean that "MS CLR is the runtime"

Answer (score 1):

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.frameworkdescription?view=net-6.0) provides the name of the .NET installation that the app is running on and the version, e.g. "Mono *version*"