# How to detect what platform my C#/F# code is running on mono or .NET?

Tags: .net, mono

I need to use .NET or MONO for C#/F# programming.
How do I know my C#/F# code is running on what platform?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect which .NET runtime is being used (MS vs. Mono)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721161/how-to-detect-which-net-runtime-is-being-used-ms-vs-mono)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do this.  However, if it's really necessary you can check for the type Mono.Runtime.  From the [Mono FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical):

```
Type t = Type.GetType ("Mono.Runtime");
if (t != null)
    Console.WriteLine ("You are running with the Mono VM");
else
    Console.WriteLine ("You are running something else");
```