# xUnit Equivalent of MSTest's Assert.Inconclusive

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, assert, xunit, assertion

What is the xUnit equivalent of the following MSTest code:

```cs
Assert.Inconclusive("Reason");
```

This gives a yellow test result instead of the usual green or red. I want to assert that the test could not be run due to certain conditions and that the test should be re-run after those conditions have been met.

Comment: In the 1.x version there was none, which version of xunit are you using? https://xunit.github.io/docs/comparisons.html

Comment: The latest version 2.1.0.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way is to use the `Skip` parameter within the `Fact` or `Theory` attributes.

```cs
[Fact(Skip = "It's not ready yet")]
public void ReplaceTokensUnfinished()
{
    var original = "";
    var expected = "";
    var tokenReplacer = new TokenReplacer();
    var result = tokenReplacer.ReplaceTokens(original, _tokens); // (_tokens is initialised in a constructor)
    Assert.Equal(result, expected);
}
```

Which gives this result when run:

[image]

Comment: I don't like this. Wouldn't this mean any exception or failure would mean the test skipped? I want the ability to only be inconclusive under certain circumstances and fail otherwise...

Comment: That's correct, it skips the test. Sounds like it can't quite do what you need. xUnit is open source though, so you can add your functionality to it ;)

Comment: Additionally, adding Skip to Theory skips all tests (for all "theories") rather than just the single run.

Comment: this is not the same. `Assert.Inconclusive()` is not only used when the test is not implemented yet, but also when there is an error in the Arrange section of the test. As of now, there is no replacement for this. 

See also [xUnit Issue #1070](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1070)

Answer (score 46):

Best thing one can do until something is implemented in the library is to use [Xunit.SkippableFact](https://github.com/AArnott/Xunit.SkippableFact):

```cs
[SkippableFact]
public void SomeTest()
{
    var canRunTest = CheckSomething();
    Skip.IfNot(canRunTest);

    // Normal test code
}
```

This will at least make it show up as a yellow ignored test case in the list.

Credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35871507/537842

Comment: Not available in .NET Core 2, .NET Standard 2, .NET Framework 4.7

Comment: Could you give a reference on that because I'm using it in a xUnit project targeting `netcoreapp2.0`.

Comment: Check your dependencies, it is not compiling for .NET Standard 2. It is compiling with .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: That's what I did. And according to the NuGet gallery it's supported even down to .NET Standard 1.1. See dependencies at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xunit.SkippableFact/

Comment: It is available in .NET Core 2 now.

Comment: Still shows up as an error in VS2022

Answer (score -4):

I normally do something like this:

```cs
throw new Exception("Inconclusive");
```

Yes, it shows as a failed test, but at least you can raise this in the test under certain inconclusive cases.

I've not used the SkippableFact feature mentioned in the other answer, but that sounds like a great solution to me.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The question is how to avoid having to do this.