# xUnit allow several test to fail

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, e2e-testing

I am currently using xUnit as a testing framework and I want to allow one or two test to fail, is there a method or config file that I can set that will give me the possibility to do that?

PS: I know that generally all of the test should run with success, but we have a specific scenario for this one

I tried to use a CollectionDefinition and then count them, but is not an elegant way to do it

Comment: Do you want to ignore the test? Or do you want to assert that a certain method throws an error of some kind?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I skip specific tests in xUnit based on current platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421328/how-do-i-skip-specific-tests-in-xunit-based-on-current-platform)

Comment: Typically testrunners will execute all tests and tell you in the end how many failed. What you do with the failed count is up to you?

Comment: Does Assert.Fail() work for you?

Comment: thanks a lot for the comments, I am not trying to skip it, I have several tests, around 100 let's say and I want to allow for 2 test to fail, it does not matter which ones. if 98 test from 100 will succeed I want xUnit to mark this as success

Comment: Still seems weird what follow up system needs to get a wrong result from the testrunner? Can't you just simply tell the follow up system that 2 errors are ok?

Comment: @Ralf I will try this, thanks for suggestion