# Skip Test cases (xUnit) running in Docker

Tags: c#, dockerfile, xunit

I recently came through this Microsoft post where I discovered that I can filter test cases based on speific parameters provided as fillter argument for C# xUnit.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests?pivots=xunit](https://stackoverflow.com)

I am running multiple test cases using a pipeline which calls a docker file executing a dotnet command to run tests as follows:

```
RUN dotnet test --runtime ubuntu.20.04-x64 \
    --logger trx \
    --results-directory /app/testreports \
    --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" \
    --filter DisplayName\!~SkipAtRuntime \
    $TestFile
```

Here, I am trying to skip test cases from running whose names contains the word "SkipAtRuntime".
There problem I am facing is that the execution of this command is not stable, meaning, the pipeline executing this command sometimes passes and sometimes fails. The reason is the above mentioned dotnet command, and error which occurs is below:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet test --runtime ubuntu.20.04-x64 \t--logger trx \t--results-directory /app/testreports \t--collect:\"XPlat Code Coverage\" \t--filter DisplayName\\!~SkipAtRuntime \t$TestFile" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Could anyone please help and let me know why is this **--filter DisplayName!~SkipAtRuntime ** command so unsatable. Or, am I not using it correctly?

Thanks in advance.

One of the test case which I wanted to skip has a name: **Test_Resetparameters_SkipAtRuntime()**

Comment: If it's unstable, try a stable solution instead, I suggest this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35871507/11309214