# How do I tell my code is running on Mono?

Tags: .net, mono

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect which .NET runtime is being used (MS vs. Mono)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721161/how-to-detect-which-net-runtime-is-being-used-ms-vs-mono)

In .net how dow I tell if my code is running on Mono?

Comment: (I got told to add as comment, sorry) Check for colour =D (I know it's cheeky but meh)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the Mono FAQ:

http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical

Below is directly from that link:

> **How can I detect if am running in Mono?**
>
> Having code that depends on the underlying runtime is considered to be
>   bad coding style, but sometimes such code is necessary to work around
>   runtime bugs. The supported way of detecting Mono is:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main ()
    {
        Type t = Type.GetType ("Mono.Runtime");
        if (t != null)
             Console.WriteLine ("You are running with the Mono VM");
        else
             Console.WriteLine ("You are running something else");
    }
}
```

> Any other hack, such as checking the underlying type of System.Int32
>   or of other corlib types, is doomed to fail in the future.

Long and short of it, just don't.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I only ask because I may need to workaround a bug.

Comment: @Simon no problem - sometimes even stuff you apparently shouldn't do is required.

Comment: turns out it is a duplicate :) but u still had a good answer

Answer (score 11):

From [mono porting guide](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_Winforms_Applications):

```
public static bool IsRunningOnMono ()
{
  return Type.GetType ("Mono.Runtime") != null;
}
```