# Monodevelop target platform

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I'm writing a library that is supposed to be cross-platform, but it needs different implementations depending on which platform I want to target. There's also a set of files that I want to include in the project for *every* target. How can I do this?

EDIT: It's also fine if I can [target a specific .NET runtime](http://monodevelop.com/Download/What%27s_new_in_MonoDevelop_2.2) (either Microsoft's .NET or Mono), and I've seen the option for this -- its in Build/General in the project options. I'm not sure this is what I need though.

ANOTHER EDIT: I'm thinking I could also use preprocessor `if`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines:Application_Portability for general guidelines and [isolate Mono-specific code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721161/how-to-detect-which-net-runtime-is-being-used-ms-vs-mono) for your fix.