# TargetFrameworks Moniker for Windows + NET Framework Version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono, cross-platform, .net-standard

In Visual Studio when working with ***.NETStandard*** project we have the option of specifying additional platforms using monikers like:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net45;net46;netstandard1.0;netstandard1.3</TargetFrameworks>
```

In above you can see that the class library project targets 4 platforms. When I compile the project does build. However, my concern is that a lot of code within the target `net45` and `net46` make use of Win32 APIs and provide utility functions for WPF based application.

I wish to isolate these utilities for projects referencing the class library (via NuGet) in Mono platforms using some macro if possible as having a WPF utility within a class library that is to be used in Mono environment would clearly lead to unprecedented consequences.

Are there any monikers that could help me explicitly specify a target for Windows-only .NET platform? Possibly from Windows 8 and upwards.

Comment: `net45` and `net46` are for Windows only .NET. You should not put Mono into consideration (though it might work in certain ways), as it is in fact out of scope. You should think that only .NET Framework/.NET Core/Xamarin are officially supported everywhere, while Mono is of its best efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not possible. There is a [proposal to add mono-specific target framework identifiers](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2320) which is kind of the inverse of what you want. If this is implemented, you could create a mono-specific version that would be used by mono instead of the `net*` specific builds.

However, you could make runtime-specific builds that are put into `runtimes/win/lib/net46/windows-specific.dll` that would be used when consuming from .NET framework projects on windows. This requires creating a custom package layout and maybe even reference assemblies to put into `ref/net46`. This dll might also be used by mono running windows.

But note that `net461`is also the fallback-framework for .NET Core 2.0 libraries so if a NuGet package only contains a `net46` build, it would be used for a .NET Core 2.0 application.

The best approach is probably to include both implementations in the library and determine [via Reflection if it the runtime being used is mono](https://stackoverflow.com/a/721194/784387).