# how to stop running test if a specific test fails in Azure devops?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, automated-tests, xunit

I have tests written using selenium and Xunit. I run them in the Azure release pipeline. I have 500+ tests, I want to make a condition if the login test fails then it won't execute other tests. How to do this in Azure DevOps or in Xunit?

Comment: You could store the login test result in a boolean somewhere and extend `FactAttribute` to skip based on that value. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421941/3005230) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Travieso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3005230/travieso). Posting your suggestions as an answer to help other community members.

Below are the different options which helps in stop running different test

**Most intrusive, compile time platform detection**

Use  `MONOWIN`  command as a precompiler flag in VS Solution. which will define an attribute and ignores the test when compiled

```cs
public class IgnoreOnMonoFactAttribute : FactAttribute {
#if MONOWIN
    public IgnoreOnMonoFactAttribute() {
        Skip = "Ignored on Mono";
    }
#endif
}
```

**somewhat intrusive - runtime platform detection**

Here is a similar solution to option1, except no separate configuration is required:

```cs
public class IgnoreOnMonoFactAttribute : FactAttribute {

    public IgnoreOnMonoFactAttribute() {
        if(IsRunningOnMono()) {
            Skip = "Ignored on Mono";
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Determine if runtime is Mono.
    /// Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721161
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if being executed in Mono, false otherwise.</returns>
    public static bool IsRunningOnMono() {
        return Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null;
    }
}
```

- The tests what ever you are performing in xunit, the `[Fact]`  should be  replaced with  `[IgnoreOnMonoFact]`
- CodeRush test runner still ran the  `[IgnoreOnMonoFact]`  test, but it did ignore the  `[Fact(Skip="reason")]`  test. I assume it is due to CodeRush reflecting xUnit and not actually running it with the aid of xUnit libraries. This works fine with xUnit runner.

For complete details check the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421941/15969833).